# Reporting Services scatter chart origin/axis placement negative values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Shown are two scatter charts on the same set of data, which contains some negative values. One is in Excel 2010 with the origin centered, the other is with Reporting Services. I would like the chart to display as in Excel. In SQL Server Reporting Services 2005-2012, is there any way to set the placement of the origin?

Excel
[image]

SSRS
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: click on each of the axes in the Report Designer and change the CrossAt property in the Properties window from `Auto` to the desired value (presumably 0).